How to unambiguously write a name with multiple of each component?
Preamble
Each PH stands for Placeholder.
Context
I'm quite normal - I've one first name, one last name, but two middle names:



First
Second (Middle)
Third (Surname)




Roke
Julian Lockhart
Beedell



Intuitively adhering to what this English SE answer describes, I've always used "Beedell, Roke Julian Lockhart" for myself, especially in places where sorting is needed, which generally works adequately.
However, sometimes, some people call me "Beedell", or another random name, like "Julian". To my knowledge, this is standard ^0 but doesn't appear to be interpreted that way. Questions like this on English SE solely confuse me further, and I expect others too. It's not ideal.
This has become especially problematic recently, when I've had to deal with some quite strange name arrangements, and want to ensure that I'm formatting these names in a way that would make sense if a 3rd-party were to read it:
Examples

Last year, I encountered a situation like this Academia SE question describes, where a (presumably) Spanish and/or Mexican I was interacting with had multiple first and last names:



First
Second (Middle)
Third (Surname)




PH0 PH1

PH4 PH5




Today, I encountered someone who had (or at least purported that they had) multiple first and middle names.



First
Second (Middle)
Third (Surname)




PH0 PH1
PH2 PH3
PH4



Poor bloke, although they seemed not to mind.
Possibility
I've investigated whether it's legally possible (to ensure that I wasn't merely lied to) and at least some anecdotes exist, like this Reddit comment.
However, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_name#cite_ref-14 is probably a more trustworthy example, because even if not English, names appear to generally be the same across languages (except in Cantonese).


Question
Consequently, I'd like to know whether convention and/or standard exists for how to write at least somewhat unambiguously a name with multiple first, second, and third names:



First
Second (Middle)
Third (Surname)




PH0 PH1
PH2 PH3
PH4 PH5



...in order to not have to revisit this again.
I'm not asking for a magic solution - names are complex and inconsistent things. I'm just looking for the most comprehensive/flexible convention or standard available, and shall use my brain to cover any edge cases it doesn't.

Being a programmer, I've wished at times whilst researching this that I could just exclaim, "Ah, screw it, I'll just use JSON"!
first: "PH0 PH1", second: "PH2 PH3", third: "PH4 PH5"

but I'd obviously be laughed at if I used that even in the context of computers, outside of a specifically programming niche.

I don't think there is any universal standard. Some entities (web site, organisation, etc) want "John Smith" others like "Smith, John". Most provide separate areas to enter each, then do with it what they will.
I think that all you can say, unless the entity requires otherwise, your best bet is your-prefered- first-name, any-middle-names, family/surname-name(s). So long as it's unambiguous.
For example I am Peter John Astra Jennings. People call me either just Peter, or Peter Jennings, but I sign PJA Jennings. One web site has got it wrong and calls me Peter John Astra, somehow mistaking Astra for my surname.
Similarly my grandson is Otis Fredric Jennings Mann. It's fairly obvious that Jennings Mann is a compound surname, particularly as Jennings is, as far as I know, never used as a middle name. But then you have to have knowledge of the permissible  naming structures in the country you are talking about.

Thank you. I hoped that this wasn't true, but expected this answer.
